# Where to locate certain functionality - in the object class methods or in the application code?

Tags: oop

It's been a very long time since I touched object oriented programming, so I'm a bit rusty and would appreciate your insight.

Given a class, for example CDPlayer, that includes the field numberOfTracks and currentTrack and the methods getCurrentTrack and setCurrentTrack, where should I put the functionality to set the current track to a random track? In a method such as setRandomTrack inside this class, or in the application code outside this class (e.g. player1.setCurrentTrack(*randomnumbergeneratingcode*))?

What are the pros and cons of each of these approaches? Which is easier to use, change and maintain? The above example is quite simple, but how do things change when I want e.g. the random number generation to be flexible - one CDPlayer instance to use a normal distribution for randomising, another to use a flat distribution, another to use a distribution defined by some set of numbers, and so forth.

EDIT

Thanks for the three replies so far.

Consider an extension to the op... After a decent amount of coding it becomes clear that on numerous occasions we've had to, in the application code, change current the track to the track three before it but only on Thursdays (which potentially has non-trivial conditional logic to work properly). It's clear that we're going to have to do so many times more throughout the dev process. This functionality isn't going to be user facing (it's useless as far as users would be concerned), it's just something that we need to set on many occasions in the code for some reason.

Do we created a setThreeTracksBeforeOnThursdays method in the class and break the tight representative model of a CD player that this class has, or do we absolutely stick to the tight representative model and keep this functionality in the application code, despite the pain it adds to the application code? Should the design wag the developers or should the developers wag the design?

Answer (score 0):

The pro of putting it inside CDPlayer is that it will be a single method call, and that the function is pretty typical of CD players so it "feels right".

A con of putting it in your application is that it requires two calls, one to get the number of tracks so you can generate the random number, and one to set it.

A con of putting it in CDPlayer is that the class needs to know about random numbers.  In this particular case, it's simple enough to use a standard library, but if this were some top security CIA CD player that could be an issue.  (Just noticed youvedited your post to hint at something similar)

I'd put the code in CDPlayer, (and add a method to change the random number generator, the fancy term for this is Dependency Injection) but this post hopefully gives you a few of the pros and cons.

Comment: "...if this were some top security CIA CD player that could be an issue."  What!? What has that to do with object-oriented design?

Comment: @Lundin  I think we'd all agree that 99.99% of the time it's o.k. for the CDPlayer class to have some knowledge of / linkage to the random number generator, e.g. have a reference to a java.util.Random.  I was trying to think of a contrived example where this should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no real benefit to where the code is besides that its more readable.

But in some cases it could be less redundant to put the code in the class, it all depends on the language. For example:

C# code in the class:

```
private Random random = new Random();

public void setRandomTrack()
{
    setCurrentTrack(random.NextInt());
}
```

C# code outside the class:

```
Random random = new Random();
CDPlayer player = new CDPlayer()
player.setCurrentTrack(random.NextInt());
```

The code outside has to create a Random Generator outside the class to generate a random integer, you might have to create the Random Generator more than once if its not visible to the class where you calling it from.

Answer (score 0):

- If it is a function that all CD players have, then it should be inside the CDPlayer class.
- If it is a function that just a few CD players have, then you should inherit the CDPlayer class and put the function in the child class.
- If it is a function that no CD player has, then there is no reason to include it in the class. Does it make sense for the `CDPlayer` class to *know* about picking random tracks? If not, it should be implemented outside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the three replies so far.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to implement this feature. What are requirements for playing random track?

- it should be random (of course),
- it should be not current track (nobody wants to hear current track five times in a row if there other tracks to play)
- you should pick track from those which exist in player (track number should not exceed count of tracks).

I will use C#:

```
Random random = new Random();
CDPlayer player = new CDPlayer();
// creates list of track indexes, e.g. { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
var tracksNotPlayed = Enumerable.Range(0, player.NumberOfTracks - 1).ToList();

if(tracksNotPlayed.Count == 0)
   // initialize list again, or stop

int index = random.Next(tracksNotPlayed.Count);
int nextTrack = tracksNotPlayed[index];
player.SetCurrentTrack(nextTrack);
tracksNotPlayed.Remove(nextTrack);
```

That looks like [feature envy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me - some other class uses data from player to implement this functionality. Not good. Let's do some refactoring - move all this stuff into player:

```
public void PlayRandomTrack() // Shuffle
{
    if(tracksNotPlayed.Count == 0)
       tracksNotPlayed = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfTracks - 1).ToList();

    int index = random.Next(tracksNotPlayed.Count);
    int nextTrack = tracksNotPlayed[index];
    SetCurrentTrack(nextTrack);
    tracksNotPlayed.Remove(nextTrack);         
}
```

It looks better and it's much easier to use outside:

```
CDPlayer player = new CDPlayer();
player.PlayRandomTrack();
```

Also if you are implementing something like Winamp (it has two modes - shuffle playing and sequential playing when it automatically plays songs one by one) then consider to move this logic into some [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (or it should be [Iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)?), which will have two implementations - sequential and shuffle, and will know nothing about player - it's responsibility will be picking number in some range (number of tracks or collection being enumerated should be passed):

```
public abstract class CollectionIterator<T>
{        
    public CollectionIterator(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
       // save source
    }

    abstract int GetNextItemIndex();
}
```

The player will use this iterators/strategies to play next item:

```
public void PlayTrack()
{
    SetCurrentTrack(iterator.GetNextItemIndex());
}
```

So, we have clear separation of responsibilities here - client uses player to listen music, player knows how to play music, and iterator knows how to pick next item from collection. You can create `ThursdaysCollectionIterator` if you want some other sequences on Thursdays. That will keep your player and client code untouched.